# Finding the max distance between two arrays

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

I have the solution of an `ode` as an array $x(t_k)$ where $k=1,...K$.

I have another array which is an approximation to the solution of the `ode`, this array has also a length $k=1,...,K$.

How can I find the `max` distance between these two arrays? In other words I want to find the accuracy of my solution-approximation.

It is correct to do (in matlab):

Assume the solution-vector is called `xSol` and the approximation-vector is called `xApprox`

`max((xSol - xApprox).^2)`

or should I just do:

`max(xSol - xApprox)`

I would appreciate some justification of the answer, so I can learn!

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do the first, then you must take the square root of the result.

The second will yield incorrect results, for example, if $x_{sol} = [0,0,0]$ and $x_{approx} = [0,10,10]$, then the maximum of their difference is $0$. What you must do is take the maximum of the absolute values of their distances. This is a function in matlab, i.e. for a vector $x=[x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n]$, the matlab function `norm(x,1)` returns $$\max\{|x_1|,|x_2|,\dots,|x_n|\}$$

For real numbers, this number is equal to $$\sqrt{\max\{x_1^2,x_2^2,\dots, x_n^2\}},$$
which is exactly the square root of the number your first formula would return.

Comment: in other words I can use both method as long as I take the `sqrt` of the first result and I use `norm(x,1)` for the second one? And could you explain me why do you say: "...then the maximum of their difference is 0"? I see that the difference of the first coordinates are zero, but not for the second and third coordinates...what am I seeing wrong?

Comment: @SergioSarmiento The difference $x_{sol} - x_{approx}$ is equal to $[0, -10, -10]$, and the maximum of this array is equal to $0$, since $0>-10$. The maximum of the absolute values of the vector is not $0$, of course.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that! It is actually what you wrote...my bad! I see the difference between `difference` and `absol value`. Another question, is I wan to use `norm(x,1)` what should I replace `x` with? `xSol` or `xApprox`?

Comment: @SergioSarmiento What do you think? What do you need? *hint* neither `xSol` or `xApprox` will do.

Comment: well, I need to find the max distance between both arrays, and `norm(x,1)` will give me the euclidean distance of `x`. So, `norm(xSol)` will only give me $\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+,,,}$ which is the distance between these points, am I  right? while `norm(xApprox)` will give me the same, distance between points, and I need `norm(xSol-xApporx,1)` but I have the feeling that this notation is not correct... I don't know 5xum, but I am trying to understand! maybe another hint?

Comment: @SergioSarmiento My only hint at this point is "be more confident", because `norm(xSol - xApprox, 1)` is precisely what you want. It is also equal to `max(abs(xSol - xApprox))` and to `sqrt(max((xSol - xApprox).^2))`. You did it!

Comment: thank you very much! It is just so amazing learning new things ans specially in mathematics!

Comment: @SergioSarmiento Happy to help.